# how to change saved gtihub password on terminal

Tags: git, github

By mistake I saved a wrong password when enter the order:

```
git push origin master
```

and nothing prompt because I saved the password and user name
it just show me the error

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/udacity/course-collaboration-travel-plans.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

What should I do to change the password on terminal? I am using fedora 27

Comment: What's the output (if any) when you run `git config --get credential.helper`? Also, are you trying to push to the [udacity/course-collaboration-travel-plans repository](https://github.com/udacity/course-collaboration-travel-plans)?

Comment: there is no output when i run git config --get credential.helper .

Comment: i am trying to push to  udacity/course-collaboration-travel-plans repository

Comment: i am using fedora not osx

Comment: I highly doubt udacity will want you (and everyone else) to push to their repository. 403 error is forbidden, not access denied from a password... You reset your password on Github.com

Answer (score 0):

For password caching, please reference the [GitHub instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/#platform-linux). I'm assuming you used this. If so, the command you'd use to flush the cache is:

```
$ git credential-cache exit
```

This is documented in the [git-credential-cache man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache).

However, you may have an underlying issue if you're trying to push directly to the [udacity/course-collaboration-travel-plans repository](https://github.com/udacity/course-collaboration-travel-plans/). Unless you have write/admin permission on the repository, a push will fail with an HTTP 403 error.

In order to collaborate with a repository that you don't have permission to write to, you'll want to:

1. fork the repository
2. create your changes within your forked instance
3. create a pull request against the original repository with your suggested changes.

For reference, here's [GitHub's documentation about pull requests](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/).

Answer (score 0):

you can run

`git credential-manager`

to list options that you need